# Regex variable in bash

Tags: regex, bash, unix

How extract specific data from my variable in Bash ?

```
myvar={"tag":"somedata", "token":"dataIWant", "...":"..."};
```

I 'm not very comfortable with unix command, specially regex.

Comment: Your data looks like JSON, do you confirm your data is the string `{"tag":"somedata", "token":"dataIWant", "...":"..."}`? Could you also specify what you want to extract so it is easier to answer you?

Comment: Bash itself possess no feature for parsing JSON directly. However, I would heartily recommend [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) as a useful, command-line tool for interacting with JSON.

Comment: In fact , I get my variable from a curl request. I want to retrive "dataIWant".

Comment: I think we had another question just like this yesterday -- including the mistaken wanting-to-use-a-regex aspect (despite regular expressions not being tools appropriately suited to parsing irregular languages). [See http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/is-json-a-regular-language ].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking kojiro's suggestion:

```
myvar=$( curl ... )
value=$( jq -r '.token' <<< "$myvar" )
echo "$value"   # ==> dataIWant
```